# Porque Delphi me muestra este error: Undeclared identifier: 'DecimalSeparator'

Tags: json, api, delphi

Estoy usando Delphi Berlin 10.1.2, acabo de iniciar un nuevo proyecto usando la libreria superobject:
https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject

Esta libreria sirve para interpretar respuestas de la API

```
function FloatToJson(const value: Double): SOString;
var
  p: PSOChar;
begin
  Result := FloatToStr(value);
  if {$if defined(NEED_FORMATSETTINGS)}FormatSettings.{$ifend}DecimalSeparator <> '.' then //Error aqui
  begin
    p := PSOChar(Result);
    while p^ <> #0 do
      if p^ <> SOChar({$if defined(NEED_FORMATSETTINGS)}FormatSettings.{$ifend}DecimalSeparator) then //Error aqui
      inc(p) else
      begin
        p^ := '.';
        Exit;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Y en esta otra funcion:

```
function CurrToJson(const value: Currency): SOString;
var
  p: PSOChar;
begin
  Result := CurrToStr(value);
  if {$if defined(NEED_FORMATSETTINGS)}FormatSettings.{$ifend}DecimalSeparator <> '.' then //Error aqui
  begin
    p := PSOChar(Result);
    while p^ <> #0 do
      if p^ <> SOChar({$if defined(NEED_FORMATSETTINGS)}FormatSettings.{$ifend}DecimalSeparator) then //Error aqui
      inc(p) else
      begin
        p^ := '.';
        Exit;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

El error es:

> Undeclared identifier: 'DecimalSeparator'

Porque sucede esto?

Answer (score 1):

De manera genérica, el error ocurre porque el compilador no encuentra la declaración del identificador `DecimalSeparator` dentro del contexto.

Interpretando el error, lo que ocurre es que la versión de la biblioteca que estás utilizando aún no soporta Delphi Berlin, cosa extraña para estas alturas, pues parece haber sido abandonada por el autor, ya que la versión más reciente es todavía una más que Berlin (Tokio).

Por fortuna, es fácil hacer tu mismo el cambio necesario.

Por lo que pude ver del fragmento de código que publicas, para que el código compile en versiones modernas de Delphi hace falta que se defina el símbolo de [compilación condicional](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)) 
`NEED_FORMATSETTINGS`.

Viendo el fuente, el cambio a hacer es el siguiente: busca este fragmento al inicio de la unidad:

```
    {$if defined(VER230) or defined(VER240)  or defined(VER250) or
         defined(VER260) or defined(VER270)  or defined(VER280)}
      {$define VER210ORGREATER}
      {$define VER230ORGREATER}
    {$ifend}
```

y cámbialo por esto:

```
    {$if ComilerVersion >= 21}{$define VER210ORGREATER}{ifend}
    {$if ComilerVersion >= 23}{$define VER230ORGREATER}{ifend}
```

Con este cambio ya no te dará problema en esta o futuras versiones de Delphi.